Clicking Calendar and Time on Taskbar from Multiple Screens
How to Make the Calendar/Time Clickable on Secondary Taskbar in Windows?
I'm using a Windows setup with multiple monitors, and I have the taskbar extended to both screens. The clock and time are displayed on both the primary and secondary taskbars, but I can only click the calendar/time on the primary monitor to open the calendar popup.
On the secondary monitor, the clock and time are visible but not interactive (clicking does nothing).
What I've Tried:

Verified that the taskbar is set to show on all displays (Taskbar Settings > Taskbar Behaviors > Show taskbar on all displays).
Ensured that apps are set to appear on "All taskbars" for consistent behavior.
Used keyboard shortcuts (e.g., Win + A) as a workaround to open the calendar, but I'd like the ability to click directly on the secondary taskbar clock.
Looked for third-party solutions like DisplayFusion or Actual Multiple Monitors, but I'd prefer a native Windows fix if possible.

Question:
Is there a way to make the clock/calendar on the secondary taskbar clickable (just like it works on the primary monitor) without relying on third-party tools? If not, are there alternative native solutions to improve this behavior?
Environment:

OS: Windows 10/11
Monitors: Two monitors with the taskbar extended to both.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
